# How to open an image?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkhQD.jpg)

I use 'openImage' package to import multiple images,

#this sets the directory

```
    list\<- list.files("C://Users//Bilal//Desktop//test//bb", all.files 
     = FALSE,full.names = TRUE)

  #this loop to import the images
  df<-data.frame()
  #df <-list()
  for (i in seq_along(lista)) {
     pic<-readImage(lista[i])
     pic<-rgb_2gray(pic)
     pic<-resizeImage(pic, width = 48, height = 64)
     pic<-as.vector(pic)
     pre_pic<-t(pic)
     df<-rbind(df,pre_pic)}
  
  #this code is used to open the image but the second line does not work
  #Error in image.default(df, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", col = grayscale) : 
  #'z' must be a matrix
  grayscale <- gray(seq(0, 1, length = 100))
  image(df[,,1], xaxt='n', yaxt='n', col=grayscale)
```

This is what I expect to see

Comment: I couldn't find the package `openimage`. Did you mean `OpenImageR`? If so, that package doesn't have the function `image`. You would use the function `imageShow()`. `grDevices` has an `image()`, as does `BiocGenerics`.

Comment: @kat yes, OpenImageR. I need to open them to do variance. imageshow does not help

Comment: I think you may have to share one of the image objects for me to help. If you run  `dput(readImage(lista[1]))`, share the output of that call. I can't seem to find an RGB image to try, and only that would work for `rgb_2gray`. Although, I should ask have you tried taking just one item from your `lista` object and running through the functions in your `for` statement to see if it's creating what you're expecting?

Comment: @kat I added an image. This is the error that I always have 'Error in image.default(img, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256))) : 
  'z' must be numeric or logical'

Answer (score 0):

I understand now what's happening; thanks for sharing the image. First- you were/are using `grDevices::image()` <- the base R function.

The error tells you that R can't determine how you shaped your data. When you flattened the matrix into a vector, you knew it was 48 x 64, but that information wasn't there when you sent it to `image`.

You could do either one of the following:

```
# before making it a vector
image(t(p3), col = grayscale, yaxt = 'n', xaxt = 'n')

# after making it a row in a data frame
image(t(matrix(unlist(df[1,]), ncol = 64, nrow = 48)),
      col = grayscale, yaxt = 'n', xaxt = 'n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works but variance did not work yet here's the code  varimg <- apply(df,1:2,var)
image(varimg, col=grayscale)

Comment: There is nothing like that in your question. When and how did you create the object `varimg`? Additionally, the function `apply` allows you to set the parameter `margin` to rows, columns, or both. However, I'm pretty sure that 1:2 isn't going to work. If you want both -> `c(1, 2)`